# Prolog - backtracking with iterator

Tags: prolog, iteration, backtracking

I have a predicate like:

```
solve(parts(X), Places) :-
    "iterate Pl from Places to 0",
    tryPutPart(X, Pl),
    fail.
```

I want to force the backtracking there, because I want all the possible solutions.(Instead I would have found the place Pl recursively in different predicate).

Is it possible to do it  somehow? I got the idea to make a list of length `Places` and looking like `[1, 2, 3.....]`, and then try to non-deterministically putout some Y from it.

The behavior I would like is if I wrote `places(0). places(1). places(2). - ... -` and so on into code and then wrote it like

```
:- places(Y), tryPutPart(X, Y).
```

Comment: You question is a bit chaotic. I don't understand what you try to achieve. Please try to reformulate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `between/3` predicate to check all integers from a given range. For example:

```
?- between(1, 10, N), N > 3, write(N), nl, fail.
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
false.
```

See http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3 for SWI-Prolog documentation on this predicate.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I used predicate `for`

```
for(M,M,N):- M < N.
for(I,M,N):- M < N, M1 is M + 1, for(I,M1,N).
```

and then you can force backtracking:

```
solve(parts(X),Places) :- for(Y, 1, TPlaces), tryPutPart(X, Y), fail.
```